# Open ports on Linksys E1000 router

Tags: router, nmap

I ran `nmap -p- -PN` on my home IP address. I'm using a VPN so presumably the scan is what the outside world would see if they ran nmap. The scan returned

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
10605/tcp open  unknown
38864/tcp open  unknown
```

My devices are connected to the Internet through a Linksys E1000 router. What are these ports for? Why are they open on the router? Can I close them? And is there a way to see what services (I have two machines, one running Win7 and the other running Ubuntu -- oh and also e-readers and cell phones) might be using them?

Comment: Doesn't look like they are known for anything specific: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers. You can use netstat -bf on the win7 machine to see if they are in use and where they are connected to. I'm sure there is a similar netstat command for ubuntu you can use.

Comment: Do you have UPNP enabled in the router configuration?  They could have been opened by an internal service if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely these are just random ports that happen to be in use at the time by machines on your network. This is 100% normal if you are using UPnP, permissive NAT, or have SPI disabled.